# ios - Xcode Terminate called throwing an exception

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

```
'NSUnknownKeyException',
reason: '[<UIApplication 0xde7b110> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key guessText.'
```

**my app keeps crashing, why?**

Comment: What's wrong with **reading** the exception message?

Comment: Have you checked that guessText is set up correctly and referenced correctly at all times?  is it duplicated between classes.  Check some other threads on this same error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key

Comment: Probably because `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` is not key value coding-compliant for the key `guessText`.

Comment: It would be great if you could add more info. Like what kind of program are you running, what is your development environment, etc. You might could try putting some try/catch statements in your program, or even simple output after function calls. Try narrowing it down some.

Comment: im running xcode 4.4 and im adding the app onto my phone which runs ios5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this can happen for lots of reasons, this error is most frequently seen when you have some view you've designed in Interface Builder that references a non-existent `IBOutlet`, in your case one called `guessText`. Perhaps you had one that you subsequently renamed or removed from your .h? Open up your NIB/storyboard in Interface Builder, and look at the outlets, and see if you can find the one that's referencing `guessText` and fix that accordingly (either delete the outlet or create the `IBOutlet` in your code).

Comment: thank you but i fixed the error... i had to set the Main Interface as blank